# Some confusion about gevent (cffi) setup

Tags: gevent, python-cffi

In Gevent 1.1, there are two backends, cython and cffi. What I confuse is [_corecffi_build.py](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/tree/v1.1.1/gevent).

In [line 331](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/v1.1.1/gevent/_corecffi_build.py#L331),

```
ffi.set_source('gevent._corecffi', _source, include_dirs=include_dirs)
```

I do not know why **ffi.set_source** does not specify **sources** to include related c files. And **_source** only contains some declarations.

How the c source files are included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "c source files" are included in a libev-specific way. In the `_source` string we `#define LIBEV_EMBED` before we `#include "libev.h"`. Setting that macro causes libev.h itself to `#include "ev.c"`, which is all the source libev needs.

Comment: Why use such way rather than specifying **sources** parameter?

Comment: Because that's just the way libev works. We have no control over that.